# Multilayer perceptron does not converge

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent, mlp

I have been coding my own multi layer perceptron in MATLAB and it compiles without error. My training data features, x, has values from 1 to 360, and the training data output, y, has the value of $\sin(x)$.

The thing is my MLP only decreases the cost for the first few iterations and will get stuck at 0.5. I have tried including momentum, but it does not help and increasing the layers or increasing the neurons does not help at all. I am not sure why this is happening.

I have uploaded the files for your reference [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/418292-how-come-my-neural-network-mlp-stop-converging-after-several-iterations).

The summary of my code is:

1. I normalize my input data either using min-max or zscore
2. Initialize random weights and bias within the range of -1 to 1

   ```
   for i = 1:length(nodesateachlayer)-1    
    weights{i} = 2*rand(nodesateachlayer(i),nodesateachlayer(i+1))-1; 
    bias{i} = 2*rand(nodesateachlayer(i+1),1)-1; 
   end
   ```
3. Then, I do a forward pass where the input is multiplied by weights and added with the bias and then activated by a transfer function (sigmoid)

   ```
   for i = 2:length(nodesateachlayer)
        stored{i} = nactivate(bsxfun(@plus,(weights{i-1}'*stored{i-1}),bias{i-1}),activation);    
    end
   ```
4. Then calculate the error then do a backward pass

   ```
   dedp = 1/length(normy)*error;
    for i = length(stored)-1:-1:1
        dpds = derivative(stored{i+1},activation);
        deds = dpds'.*dedp;
        dedw = stored{i}*deds; 
        dedb = ones(1,rowno)*deds;
        dedp = (weights{i}*deds')';
        weights{i}=weights{i}-rate.*dedw;
        bias{i}=bsxfun(@minus,bias{i},rate.*dedb');
    end
   ```
5. I have the cost plotted out at every iteration to see the descent

I assume there is something wrong with the code so where could the error possibly lie in it?

Comment: Have you tried making any predictions on hold-out data? Which value range do you use?

Comment: I think something has to be wrong inside your backprop implementation. The code you uploaded is quite a lot and I doubt many people here will read it. Can you outline the important parts of your implementation and explain? E.g. how you calculate your gradients and update the weights

Comment: @n1k31t4 I did not. Because the cost always descends until around 0.5 and stop descending

Comment: @André thanks for the suggestions. Yes i am also thinking there's something wrong that's why I re-coded the entire MLP. At first I thought is the cost which I define wrongly since it suppose to be singular value and in my code, it's an array. After modification, the same thing still happen. and I have no idea where the hell went wrong

Comment: What's the value you set for `nodesateachlayer`? It seems you didn't share the code to run your functions.

Comment: @user12075 all the code has been shared at the link provided above. As for the value set for nodesateachlayer, first layer is the input layer so it's set according to number of features, the following is the hidden layers so if user set [3 4 5] means 3 hidden layer with 3, 4 and 5 neurons at each hidden layer respectively. the last layer is the output layer which is the number of output, since it's a regression problem so its only one

Comment: @ChanTK I was asking you to clarify your choice for `nodesateachlayer` so that people can better assist you. In **no where** in your code you wrote down [3 4 5]. BTW [3 4 5] is way too small. If you use [512] (just one hidden layer with 512 units) you should be able to get much better result (around 0.07 MSE).

Comment: @user12075 oh, i was using [5 6 7] as the number of neurons at each layer. anyway, it doesn't work like you said. As mentioned, I have tried changing the number of layers and neurons but the cost still get stuck at around 0.5. on a side note, i tend to avoid using >100 neurons as I'm under the impression it will cause overfitting and from my experience <100 neurons seems to do the task

Comment: This thread explained in details on predicting sin(x) https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19365/predict-sinus-with-keras-feed-forward-neural-network

Answer (score 0):

My view on your question, is that tiny networks seldom work. The above method uses a Neural Network to learn the function $y=\sin(x)$. Although this problems seems simple, it cannot be expected to be solved by a really tiny network (the above model uses a 5-layer MLP with hidden size [5,6,7], which is small).

Even if back-propagation is implemented correctly, would the model learn anything? No. I suppose Tensorflow implemented back-propagation correctly, here is the result using Tensorflow:
[image: fig1]

You see, it learns almost **nothing**. In fact, the MSE loss is very close to 0.5 as stated above.

My suggestion is to try a 3 layer MLP with hidden size 256. Here is the result:

[image: fig2]

You can see it's much better. MSE<0.1 now.

------------------code---------------------

```
x_ =np.atleast_2d(np.arange(0,360,1)).T
y_ = np.atleast_2d(np.sin(x_/180*np.pi))
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    with tf.variable_scope("mlp"):
        input_x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
        input_y = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,1], dtype=tf.float32)
        layer1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=input_x, units=256, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
        #layer2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=input_x, units=6, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
        #layer3 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=input_x, units=7, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
        output_y = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer1, units=1) # inputs=layer1
        loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(input_y, output_y)
        train_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(300):
            _, loss_ = sess.run((train_op, loss), feed_dict={input_x:x_, input_y:y_})
        y_hat_ = sess.run(output_y, feed_dict={input_x:x_, input_y:y_})
        print(loss_, end='\t')
plt.plot(x_,y_, 'g', x_,y_hat_,'b')
plt.legend(['ground truth', 'predicted'])
```